# why does mymysqli delete button doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to delete a product from the table, but it does not work.
Is the script wrong? How can I correct it?

```
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('functions.php');      
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    mysqli_query( $conDB, "DELETE FROM products WHERE  name='$_POST[hidden]'");
};              
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;           
    $per_page = 10; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.             
$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;                  
$statement = "products ORDER BY id DESC";
$results = mysqli_query($conDB, "SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");    
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {        
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" colspan='2' ><big style="color:red" ><b><?php echo $row['name']?></b></big><td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left" colspan='2'><big style="color:333333"><b><?php echo $row['category']?></b> / <?php echo $row['subcategory']?></big></td>
</tr>   
<tr>    
    <td style="vertical-align:top" >
       <?php echo "<img border=3 width= 300px  height =250px src=\"products/"  . $row['picture']>?>"<br /> 
</td>
     <td  style="vertical-align:top">   
            <?php echo  nl2br($row['description'])?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="$name" ><input type="submit" name="delete" onClick='return confirmDelete()' value='Delete Product'></td>
```

When I delete the "delete product" the confirmation will show if I will delete it. but after the confirmation. it does not delete the selected row from the table.

There is no show of error from php after the confirmation. Why is it happening and
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the hidden value, it seems its not written properly in the markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="$name" >
                                    <!--  ^ literal string, not a variable value -->
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
```

Sidenote: Since you're already using mysqli, why not utilize prepared statements.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete = $_POST['delete'];
    $del = $conDB->prepare('DELETE FROM products WHERE name = ?');
    $del->bind_param('s', $delete);
    $del->execute();
}
```

I suggest do it like this, remove the hidden input and use this instead:

```
<button type="submit" name="delete" onClick='return confirmDelete()' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete Product</button>
```

Comment: @jhonalynnequin by the way, is this inside a `<form>` tag?

Comment: @jhonalynnequin check out my revison, i just changed the deletion part

Comment: i did, but no luck of deleting.

Comment: @jhonalynnequin no errors? try `var_dump($_POST['delete'])`, see if its catched

Comment: it shows "string 'Delete Product' (length=14)" sorry I'm new in php. still no erros and still it does not work.

Comment: @jhonalynnequin okay, check my revision again i added an info

Comment: it does work when i change id into name. i'll just find a way to make it work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your input hidden field:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "DELETE FROM products WHERE  name='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

and then try executing the sql or modify

```
"DELETE FROM products WHERE  name='".$_POST[hidden]."'"
```